# Custom switch not hiding sub-fields on Customizer's load

Tags: theme-customizer

I created a custom switch control which is working fine. The default functionality is when it is set to 0, It hides the sub-options. This is working fine when the switch control is toggled to 0, but it doesn't work on customizer load.

Below is the code for **Custom Switch Control Class**.

```
class Custom_Customize_Switch_Control extends WP_Customize_Control {
/**
 * Enqueue scripts/styles for the WP custom switch
 */
public function enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-switch', plugin_url( 'admin/js/custom-switch.js' ), array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-switch', plugin_url( 'admin/css/custom-switch.css' ) );
}

protected function render_content() {
    $val = $this->value();
?>
    <span class="customize-control-title"><?php echo esc_html( $this->label ); ?></span>
    <?php if( !empty( $this->description ) ) { ?>
    <span class="description customize-control-description"><?php echo esc_html( $this->description ); ?></span>
    <?php } ?>

    <div class="custom-switch clearfix">
        <label class="cb-enable<?php if( $val ) echo ' selected'; ?>"><span><?php echo isset( $this->on_label ) ? esc_attr( $this->on_label ) : 'Yes' ?></span></label>
        <label class="cb-disable<?php if( !$val ) echo ' selected' ?>"><span><?php echo isset( $this->off_label ) ? esc_attr( $this->off_label ) : 'No' ?></span></label>
        <input type="hidden" class="checkbox" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $val ); ?>" <?php $this->link(); ?> />
    </div>
<?php
}
}
```

**Custom Switch Control Class JS**

```
(function( $ ) {
$(document).on('click', ".cb-enable", function () {
    var parent = $(this).parents('.custom-switch');
    $('.cb-disable', parent).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.checkbox', parent).attr('value', 1).trigger('change');

}).on('click', ".cb-disable", function () {
    var parent = $(this).parents('.custom-switch');
    $('.cb-enable', parent).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.checkbox', parent).attr('value', 0).trigger('change');
});
})( jQuery );
```

**Custom Switch Control - Notice Bar**

```
$wp_customizer->add_setting( 'cookie-notifications', array(
        'default' => 0,
        'transport' => 'postMessage'
    ));

    $wp_customizer->add_control( new Custom_Customize_Switch_Control( $wp_customizer, 'cookie-notifications', array(
        'label' => __( 'Show Notifications', '' ),
        'section' => 'custom-notice-bar-section',
        'priority' => 0
    )));
```

**Custom Switch Control - Notice Bar Fields**

```
$wp_customizer->add_setting( 'custom-notifications-text', array(
        'default' => __( 'This website uses cookies.', '' ),
        'transport' => 'postMessage',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'custom_text_sanitization'
    ));
    $wp_customizer->add_control( 'custom-notifications-text', array(
        'label' => __( 'Notice Content', '' ),
        'section' => 'custom-notice-bar-section',
        'priority' => 2
    ));
```

**Customizer.js code**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
var c = wp.customize;

c.bind('ready', function () {
    c('cookie-notifications', function (control) {
        control.bind(function (controlValue) {
            if( controlValue === '1' ) {
                c.control('amp-wp-notifications-text').activate();
            } else {
                c.control('amp-wp-notifications-text').deactivate();
            }
        });
    });
});
});
```